# Metadata query failed for: Breeze JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I was developing Breeze JS To Dos app using ASP.net Web Api. When I request to the resource I'm getting "Metadata query failed for: odata/Todos/Metadata; NaN". But when I manually request to /odata/Todos/Metadata it works fine. Do you have any idea bout this?

Comment: Can you show some sample code that isn't working?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: "http://localhost:2099/api/yourcontent/",
    hasServerMetadata: false,
});

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: dataService });
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the MaxDataServiceVersion header from datajs to cause 404s...

Try

```
var oldClient = OData.defaultHttpClient;
var myClient = {
    request: function (request, success, error) {
        delete request.headers.MaxDataServiceVersion;
        return oldClient.request(request, success, error);
    }
};
OData.defaultHttpClient = myClient;
```